# Turn off selection mode after I-searching for the word that was found

Tags: emacs

After searching for a word using an I-search, the selection mode remains enabled and pressing the escape button just once does not turn it off.

Is it possible to search for a word (forwards / backwards) and quickly go on about my business without pressing a bunch of keys to exit out of the select mode?

Also, the selection mode looks useful -- is there any way to turn it on / off without first performing a search?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "select(ion) mode"? Do you just want to know that you can "Type RET to exit, leaving point at location found." (`C-h k C-s`) ??

Comment: With the settings that I have, the word remains highlighted / selected after performing an i-search.  Pressing the RET key does indeed exit the i-search, but to turn the highlight / selection off requires a C-g or a few ESC.  It just seems like a lot of keys to exit a search --  i.e., initiate the i-search, type the name of the word, hit RET to find the word, then when the word is found hit RET again, and then the word is highlighted, so time to press C-g.  After 25 years of word-processing, I'm accustomed to search for the word and hit the escape key one time.  Reducing RET + C-g to one key?

Comment: There are times where this select feature could be very useful, similar to the Alt-F4 (turn on block) of the old WordPerfect era -- that would be a nifty trick (without requiring a search to turn it on / off) if I could learn how to do it.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? (and on which platform?). Normal behaviour is: type `C-s` to initiate isearch, type what you're searching for (repeating `C-s` to iterate through the matches), and type `RET` to exit. You do not have to type `RET` to *begin* searching (unless you used `C-s RET` initially), and the highlighting of the matching terms ceases as soon as you exit the search. I suspect you have some other configuration causing these issues. Run `emacs -Q` to see the default behaviour.

Comment: emacs -Q gives me a terminal, which is a little bit different than the fancy GUI that I'm used to seeing.  Perhaps the behavior I'm experiencing is related to `(delete-selection-mode 1)`?  Ctrl-Space deletes the found word, so that's not going to help.

Comment: I'm running the most recent build of Emacs for OSX 24.3 from the trunk, and also the nightly build of Aquamacs.  They both have the same behavior with my init.el settings.

Comment: Hmm. `emacs` and `emacs -Q` should either both run in the terminal, or both launch the GUI version. I wouldn't expect that to vary between them? I don't know much about OSX though. If you comment out (or rename) your init file, you'll almost certainly be able to confirm the default behaviour that way (as an alternative to using `-Q`), and then you can start to track down which part of your init file is responsible.

Comment: I'm running Gnu Emacs 24.3.1 on OS X. I have `delete-selection-mode` enabled as well but I do not see the behavior you're describing. The default behavior for isearch is that `RET` will exit the search and leave nothing selected. When you say that selection is still enabled, do you mean that you have selected from the place where you started the search, or only the final match? If I set the mark before I search (`C-SPC C-s ....`) then exiting the search with `RET` keeps the selection. But in that case I'm explicitly asking for that behavior...

Comment: `glucas` hit the nail on the head -- i.e., `transient-mark-mode`.  I had also unwittingly remapped C-SPC to something else, which complicated the troubleshooting process.  I believe OSX comes with an older version of Emacs pre-installed, so when I ran emacs-Q from the terminal, it was not activating the newer installation.  Thank you `phils` for helping me troubleshoot the issue -- greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `transient-mark-mode` enabled, which is now the default Emacs behavior. (It was not enabled by default in older versions of Emacs). If you're not familiar with it you may want to read about it in the Emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html).

You can set the mark (begin selection) using Control-space (`C-SPC`, the default key binding for `set-mark-command`). Then you can use other navigation keys to extend the selected region before you operate on it. For example: `C-SPC` to set the mark, `M-f M-f` to extend the selection forward two words, `C-w` to delete the selected region.

If you set the mark before beginning an incremental search, the search acts as a navigation command and extends the selected region. Exiting the search will leave the entire region selected from the place where you set the mark to the place where you exited the search. Note that this is not the default behavior for `isearch-forward` however.

Comment: Yep, that was it!  You killed two birds with one stone -- i.e., you taught me how to select a block (like alt+f4 in WordPerfect from the olden days), and disabling transient-mark-mode in the init.el fixes the issue with it being automatically triggered when using i-search.  I had also unwittingly re-mapped C-SPC to something else, so I changed it so that C-SPC can work with transient-mark-mode like it is supposed to.  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help! There's still a piece of the puzzle missing, though. I have transient-mark-mode enabled and it does not interfere with isearch by default. Somehow in your case the mark was getting activated before the search.

Comment: `Mark saved where search started` is the message I get when exiting the i-search, but at least I no longer have to press C-g to turn off the selection.  I now have `(transient-mark-mode 0)` in my init.el.

Comment: Yep, `glucas` hit the nail on the head again.  I borrowed the right-click context menu from Aquamacs and am using it with the generic Emacs -- long story short, the file I borrowed contains a specially defined i-search that is linked to Command-F, which I hit instinctively.  So now I re-enabled transient-mark-mode (i.e., I removed my 0 command above), and now i-search works like it is supposed to work.  The comments by `glucas` stuck in my head, and a light just popped on that enabled me to track it down and completely resolve the behavior I was experiencing.  Thank you so very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

just press ENTER to end the search.

if you mean that the selection area is displayed, you can unmark it with Ctrl-Space.

but I am not sure this answers your question.

--dmg

Comment: Thank you very much -- I had unwittingly remapped Ctrl-SPC and it made it more difficult for me to connect the dots regarding the root cause of what I was seeing (i.e., transient-mark-mode being enabled by default, which in turn affects i-search functionality).